# Is there a way I can combine functions and add them to more than one array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
$scope.fetching = [];
$scope.loading = [];
$scope.fetching.start = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index == 0)
        this.push(activity)
};
$scope.fetching.success = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.splice(index, 1);
};
$scope.loading.start = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index == 0)
        this.push(activity)
};
$scope.loading.success = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.splice(index, 1);
};
```

I store inside one array a list of all things that are loading and in another array a list of all things that are fetching. To use these I code something like the following:

```
$scope.fetching.start("Fetching new topics");
$scope.fetching.success("Fetching new topics");
$scope.loading.start("Loading new ideas");
$scope.loading.success("Loading new ideas");
```

Is there a way that I could make it so I would not have to reuse exactly the same code for the fetching and loading arrays?

Comment: `$scope.loading.start = $scope.fetching.start` ?

Comment: Of course. Just assign the same function to both. What's the issue?

Comment: Yes thanks. I changed it to $scope.fetching start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array/objects have the same structure, you could write a function that builds objects of that type.

```
function buildModifiedArray() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.start = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index == 0)
        this.push(activity)
  };
  arr.success = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.splice(index, 1);
  };
  return arr;
}

$scope.fetching = buildModifiedArray();
$scope.loading = buildModifiedArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the non-standard `__proto__` property is supported, you could do something like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PC8LD/2)):

```
function Test()
{   var a = [];
    a.__proto__ = Test.prototype;
    return a;
}

Test.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype,
{ start:
    { enumerable: false
    , configurable: true
    , writable: true
    , value: function (activity)
        {   var index = this.indexOf(activity);
            if (index == 0) this.push(activity);
        }
    }
, success:
    { enumerable: false
    , configurable: true
    , writable: true
    , value: function (activity)
        {   var index = this.indexOf(activity);
            if (index >= 0) this.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

$scope.fetching = Test();
$scope.loading = Test();
```

Comment: Your code looks very impressive. I am using IE9 and above so would that be okay with your code?

Comment: @Alan: unfortunately not, sadly enough. It's the only way of actually having it as a _true_ array while being able to define a prototype for it other than assigning to `Array.prototype`. Probably Tibos's answer would not be too bad though.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating a class for your task:

```
function LoadArray() {
    // ...
}
LoadArray.prototype = [];
LoadArray.prototype.start = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index == 0)
        this.push(activity)
};
LoadArray.prototype.success = function (activity) {
    var index = this.indexOf(activity);
    if (index >= 0)
        this.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.loading = new LoadArray();
$scope.fetching = new LoadArray();
```

This is supported even by IE6, in case you were wondering.